# AngularJS - How to detect window resize + landscape / portrait orientation change event

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've been trying some of the other suggestions I was able to find here on SO, but none worked. Basically, I need to update (re-render) a custom directive when the window size changes.

#### My code is the following:

```
angular.module('dynamicSlideBox', []).directive('hgDynamicSlideBox', [
  '$timeout', '$ionicSlideBoxDelegate', '$ionicScrollDelegate', '$window', function($timeout, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $ionicScrollDelegate, $window) {
    var linkFunction;
    linkFunction = function(scope, element, attrs, parent) {
      var disableScroll, ionContent, ionContentDelegate, ionicSlideBoxDelegate, modal, slideChanged, slideHandle, slider;
      slider = angular.element(element);
      modal = slider.closest('.popup-body');
      ionContent = slider.closest('.hg-dynamic-content');
      ionContentDelegate = ionContent.attr('delegate-handle');
      slideHandle = slider.attr('delegate-handle');
      ionicSlideBoxDelegate = $ionicSlideBoxDelegate;
      ionicSlideBoxDelegate.$getByHandle(slideHandle).enableSlide(false);
      if (slideHandle) {
        ionicSlideBoxDelegate = ionicSlideBoxDelegate.$getByHandle(slideHandle);
      }
      disableScroll = JSON.parse("[" + attrs.disableSlideScroll + "]");
      slideChanged = function() {
        $timeout((function() {
          $ionicScrollDelegate.resize();
        }), 50).then(function() {
          var currSlide, maxHeight, maxWidth, slideContents, slides;
          currSlide = ionicSlideBoxDelegate.$getByHandle(slideHandle).currentIndex() || 0;
          maxWidth = slider.width() + 'px';
          if (indexOf.call(disableScroll, currSlide) >= 0) {
            $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle(attrs.scrollHandle).freezeScroll(true);
          }
          maxHeight = 'none';
          slideContents = angular.element(slider[0].querySelectorAll('ion-slide > .dynamic-slider-wrapper > *'));
          slides = angular.element(slider[0].querySelectorAll('ion-slide > .dynamic-slider-wrapper'));
          slideContents.css('max-height', maxHeight);
          $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop();
          maxHeight = slides[currSlide].getBoundingClientRect().height + 20 + 'px';
          slideContents.css('width', maxWidth);
          modal.css('height', maxHeight);
          $timeout((function() {
            $ionicScrollDelegate.resize();
          }), 50);
        });
      };
      scope.$on('slideBox.slideChanged', slideChanged);
      $timeout(slideChanged, 50);
      scope.$on('destroy', function() {
        element.remove();
      });
      angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
        console.log("resized window");
        ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();
        $ionicScrollDelegate.resize();
        ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();
        scope.$digest();
      });
    };
    return {
      require: "^ionSlideBox",
      restrict: 'A',
      link: linkFunction
    };
  }
]);
```

This is a custom directive that extends the ionic slide directive so that the content resizes based on the size of the window.
This part works but only on slide change (as you can see from this `slideChanged()` function).

Now I need to resize it on window size change (on mobile, if you navigate from landscape to portrait, for example.

Can someone explain why this onResize (neither the console log) works?
How can I achieve this?

Ideally, it would be nice to just refresh the width but also a re-render is acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve this by using `resize` listener for desktop/mobile + `orientationchange` listener for mobile. `resize` is not triggered when changing the orientation on a mobile device. There is an unique event to listen on that action and it's called `orientationchange`.

Please note that `angular.element().bind()` is deprecated, you should use `.on()`.

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $window) {

    //window resize listener
    angular.element($window).on('resize', function() {
      console.log("resized window");
    });

    //switching from landscape / portrait listener
    angular.element($window).on('orientationchange', function() {
      console.log("orientation change");
    });
});
```

**>> [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oykb4fqb/)**

#### Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it a try

Comment: It still doesn't work. Can it be related to the fact that it's is in a directive?

Comment: @Nick Mhm,no. Could you create a plnkr to reproduce your problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oykb4fqb/1/ here's an example. None of the two events are firing

Comment: @Nick I tested it with your plnkr (chrome, firefox). It's working fine. Both events were fired when resize / orientation has been changed.

Comment: I am still not seeing them firing. Ill try again later. Thanks for now

Comment: @Nick, I added an screencapture to show you my test.

Comment: Ok thanks. Ill try it tonight with my real directive to see if it has something to do with my code instead. Thanks for now

Comment: my bad, I had filters on. Info was not displayed in the console. It is working now. Thanks and sorry for the waste of time :)